# Distributed transaction aborted by MSDTC

Tags: sql-server, msdtc

How to resolve the error 8522 in SQL Server 2005?

I'm getting this error while I'm loading data from the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to be more descriptive, but [this post by Paul McMillan](http://blogs.conchango.com/paulmcmillan/archive/2005/10/17/2277.aspx) suggests a possible problem and solution.